# How to Open a text file utilising VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, directory, fopen, feof

Run into an issue with some code i wrote where i want to open a txt file and then display the name and grades of the people in said text file. The code i am using is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
char name[10];
int marks[4];
};

int main()
{
    struct student s[5];
    int i=0;
    FILE *fp=fopen("Grades.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Opening the input file\n");
        return-1;
    }
    else 
        printf("File Opening successfully\n");
    
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s", s[i].name);
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            fscanf(fp,"%d", &s[i].marks[j]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("The Grade details ....\n");
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n",s[i].name);
        for( int j=0; j<4; j++)
                printf("%d\n", s[i].marks[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

No matter how i structure the code i get error file\a.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

If i have done something wrong please let me know!

Peter
55
66
44
67
Lilly
100
90
43
89
John
34
56
78
65
Mary
45
56
78
90
Alex
30
45
65
54

Comment: I'm not sure how VSCode has anything to do with this issue;  It's not the cause of bugs in code....

Comment: So, my code specifically is the problem, got it. Do you have any idea as to why. I'm not 100% sure where the fault lies.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your program yourself](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/11107541)? Doing some debugging can help you provide a [mre].

Comment: The code seems to work fine on https://onlinegdb.com/xumw6yXTR If I had to guess, I would say that your `Grades.txt` file is not in the same folder as your project, or is named incorrectly (Case sensitive on mac/linux, maybe?).  It's not exactly obvious from what you've posted.  also, `file\a.exe` looks like maybe you have compiler options putting your exe in a subfolder where the file isn't located?  All just guesses.

Comment: Ah i see, i'll try and narrow down my question next time. Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is likely returning -1 because it cannot open `Grades.txt`:

```c
FILE* fp = fopen("Grades.txt","r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Opening the input file\n");
    return -1;
}
```

If you are running this from inside Visual Studio/Visual Studio Code it is likely that `Grades.txt` does not exist in the same folder as the executable file.

If you really want to hardcode the filepath, try specifying an *absolute* path rather than a relative one: `fopen("C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Grades.txt","r");`

`"Grades.txt"` by itself is a relative path, so it needs to exist in the same folder/directory as the program.